# Spring boot ( spring batch) configuration disable the automatic creation of the database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using Spring-boot with Spring-Batch, I have  datasource config in my application.properties, but i don't want spring batch to create tables in my database, so for that I use the following configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Bean
public Job myJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener()).flow(step2()).end().build();
}

@Bean
public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(final JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
    JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
    jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
    return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
}

@Bean
public Step step2() {
    LOGGER.info("step2");
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2").tasklet(new PurchaseStatusBatch()).build();
}

@Bean
public JobOperator jobOperator() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();
    jobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer());
    jobOperator.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher());
    jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry());
    jobOperator.setJobRepository(getJobRepo());
    return jobOperator;
}

@Bean
public JobRegistry jobRegistry() {
    return new MapJobRegistry();
}

@Bean
public JobExplorer jobExplorer() throws Exception {

    MapJobExplorerFactoryBean factoryExplorer = new MapJobExplorerFactoryBean(
            new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(getTransactionManager()));
    factoryExplorer.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factoryExplorer.getObject();
}

@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepo());
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
}

@Bean
public JobRepository getJobRepo() throws Exception {
    return new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(getTransactionManager()).getObject();
}
}
```

I use `spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false` to disable the automatic creation of the database tables

During first run of the application, everything works fine but when i try to lanch my job I get MySQLSyntaxErrorException :

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table
>   'BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have disabled the auto-generation of the tables, you still need some way to have these entities available. Spring Batch has two mechanisms for that. You can create these database tables manually or through a schema manager such as Liquibase. To do that, use the SQL files found in the spring batch core resources https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources. Otherwise, you can use an in-memory representation of these tables.